# How do I update an element on my page with a callback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a element on my page that looks like this

```
<td><span class="badge badge-danger">Stopped</span></td>
```

and I want to update it based on things that are going on in the code.

Take this example.. I have a button and that element, and when I click that button I want to start downloading a list of names. Once it's started I want the text inside that span to say "Started" rather than "Stopped" and than once the code finished running aka the list of names has been downloaded, I want it to say "Done" rather than "Started"

And I've been reading back and forth about how to do this and it seems as if I need to implement ajax somehow and I'm not sure how to.

I guess the button would invoke a asp-action="StartDownload" and then it would look something like this..

```
    public ActionResult StartDownload()
    {
       StartDownload();
       return View("WhereSpanIs");
    }


private void StartDownload()
{
   //Set span text to "Started" some how

   //Finished download

   //Set span text to "Done" some how
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For manipulating HTML in the browser when requested by a controller method  as in your approach, you would need something like [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to enable communication between the server (i.e. controller) and client (i.e. browser).

As you already found out, it's easier using [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to update the text in this case (using JavaScript/[JQuery](https://jquery.com/)). Like in the following example, you could set the text when the button has been clicked, and when the request is complete:

In the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // call this method on button click
    function startDownload() {
        // loading, TODO: update the text)
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("StartDownload", "Home")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {/* done, TODO: update the text */ },
            error: function() { /* error, TODO: update the text }
        });
    }
</script>
```

In the (Home) controller:

```
public ActionResult StartDownload()
{
    // TODO: perform the download
    return Json(new {status = "OK"});
}
```

[JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is used to allow the result to be interpretable in JavaScript, although it is not used in this example.
See the [Shopping Cart Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8) for further information.